# Thumbnails not carrying over CSS in Umbraco 7

Tags: html, css, umbraco, media, thumbnails

I'm having trouble making my thumbnails behave correctly in my Umbraco project.

I'm using a for loop to display the thumbnails from a multiple media picker property editor.

```
<ul class="hide-bullets">
                        @for (var i = 0; i < images.Count; i++)
                        {
                        <li class="">
                            <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-@i"><img class="thumbnail-img" src='@images[i].Url'></a>
                        </li>
                        }
                    </ul>
```

My original template just uses static images:

```
<ul class="hide-bullets">
                                <li class="">
                                    <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-0"><img class="thumbnail-img" src="images/sommerhuse/ebeltoft/1.jpg"></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="">
                                    <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-1"><img class="thumbnail-img" src="images/sommerhuse/ebeltoft/2.jpg"></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="">
                                    <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-2"><img class="thumbnail-img" src="images/sommerhuse/ebeltoft/3.jpg"></a>
                                </li>
</ul>
```

I have included the exact same CSS files in each project, but they're displayed differently on the page.

This is how they look in my original template: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVcqX.png

And this is how they look in my Umbraco project: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0J65.png

The "thumnail-img" class that is added to images does only 2 things:

```
.thumbnail-img {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

Both projects include images with differing resolutions.

What could be the cause of this? Is Umbraco overwriting my styles, or does the media picker change how the images are being displayed?

Comment: May be the statics image example have different resolution but same height ?  . Is it ok to fix width and height to specific image size ?

Comment: One of the static images has a different height, but are aligned horizontally with the other images. Fixing the width and height could maybe work.

Comment: try changing % to px and see if it what you want ?   ex: width: 100px; height: 100px;  or you could do  width : 100%; height : 100px;

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: no, the media picker does not changes the images, it only returns the url.

You are returning the complete image while the first screenshot uses squared images.

You could crop the images automatically using the build in [Image Cropper](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/getting-started/backoffice/property-editors/built-in-property-editors/image-cropper).

```
<img src="@Url.GetCropUrl(mediaItem, height: 300, width: 300)" />
```